# Screen Black Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, video

Recently, I installed Ubuntu 16.04.  Unfortunately, my video card is really old (ATI/ Radeon X300/550) and sometimes get Black Screen and there is necessary restart and include nomodeset in GRUB.

What can I do for reinstall other driver generic or another alternative and solve the problem definitely? Any advice please?

Answer (score 0):

You could install Lubuntu which requires little in terms of graphics.

I tried it in an old computer and it worked like a charm.  Of course, the graphics since they are not the fancy 3D graphics of Unity, are not as impressive.  However, under the hood it will be the very same great operating system.

The procedure for installing Lubuntu is the same as installing Ubuntu, all you need to do is download the correct ISO.  You can get help and links to the latest ISO here: [Lubuntu/InstallingLubuntu, in Ubuntu.com](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/InstallingLubuntu)